# pop up window opeing in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am opeing a new pop up window like this in rails 3

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/images/signin_lin.jpg"), linkedin_connect_path, :popup => true %>
```

also i tried this

```
link_to image_tag("/images/signin_lin.jpg"), { :action => "connect" }, :popup => ['new_window','height=300,width=600']
```

first one does open a new window and the page comes in full size when i use the second one i get the new window but the parent window becomes blank and once the even is completed than the controller goes to new pop up window where it's size is very small.

what i want is once the new pop up window is opened and the action is done, the pop up window should be closed and the controll should come to the parent window.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some CSS and Javascript!

Here's an example you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/cdpZg/

Copying it here, just in case.

HTML:

```
<div id='user'>I am a user. Move your mouse over me</div>
<div id='popup'>Extended info about a user</div>
<div>I a piece of useless information. No use hovering over me.</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popup {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 8px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#user').hover(function() {
        $('#popup').show();
    }, function() {
        $('#popup').hide();
    });
});
```